# Load assemblies from other location

Tags: c#, assemblies

I want to load my assemblies from a "C:\Users\someUser\AppData\someFolder" location not from app folder

How can I accomplish this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can read about how the [runtime locates assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf.aspx) and use [codebases or probing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15hyw9x3.aspx).

Comment: @user859763, `something gone` wrong you are saying? Could you be a little more precise? Did the microwave oven in the kitchen started by itself?

Comment: no microwave didn't start by itself, I turned it in. I got FileNotFound exception.I tried this
     <runtime><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">. Or I did wrong?
        <probing privatePath="C:\Program Files (x86)\somefolder\somefolder"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>

Answer (score 1):

Read this MS article on how to load other assemblies to your appdomain

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837908

Comment: But I'm bit a newbie, so I didn't understood how this can help load referenced assemblies :)